# Nested observable only propagates error after timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a method in my component that uses observable to listen to first event and has a timeout of 15s. The method calls a nested observable that should throw an error if the parameter is null or empty. I use Observable.throw() but the error only propagates after the timeout/15s.

```
this.signUp(this.user)
            .first()
            .timeout(15000)
            .subscribe((authResponse) => {
                console.log("next fired");
                dialogs.alert("Next: " + authResponse);
            }, (error) => {
                //fired only after 15s when mobile is empty
                console.log("error fired");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }, () => {
                console.log("completed fired");
            });
```

signUp()

```
public signUp(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
        let observable = new Subject<AuthResponse>();
        this.isUserExisting(user.mobile)
            .first()
            .subscribe((isUserExisting) => {
                if (isUserExisting) {
                    console.log("User already exists");
                    observable.next(AuthResponse.USER_EXISTING);
                } else {
                    console.log("User does not exist");
                    this.saveUser(user).first().subscribe(() => {
                        observable.next(AuthResponse.SUCCESS);
                    })
                }
            }, (error) => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })
        return observable;
    }

    public isUserExisting(mobile: string): Observable<boolean> {
        let observable = new Subject<boolean>();
        if (!mobile) {
            console.log("empty mobile");
            return Observable.throw(new Error("Mobile number cannot be empty"));
        }
        firebase.query(() => { }, "/users",
            {
                singleEvent: true,
                orderBy: {
                    type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                    value: "mobile"
                },
                range: {
                    type: firebase.QueryRangeType.EQUAL_TO,
                    value: mobile
                }
            }
        ).then((result) => {
            console.log("Checking for user success: ");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            observable.next(result.value != null);
        });
        return observable;
    }
```

Update:
saveUser()

```
public saveUser(user: User) {
        return Observable.defer(() => firebase.push('/users', user)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("Created user record with key: " + result.key);
                console.log("Dumping result:");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error while saving user: " + error);
            })
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad practice to create your own subject on which you will emit observable values which have been emitted by an internal subscribed observable. This leads to memory leaks because you have no way to unsubscribe from your internal subscription.

```
public signUp(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
  return this.isUserExisting(user.mobile)
    .flatMap(isExistingUser => {
      if (isExistingUser) {
        console.log('user already exists: ' + isUserExisting);
        return Rx.Obserable.of(AuthResponse.USER_EXISTING);
      }
      return saveUser(user).map(result => AuthResponse.SUCCESS)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`error during signup of user: ${user.mobile})`);
      return Rx.Observable.of(AuthResponse.FAILED_TO_SIGNUP);
    })
    .first();
}
```

Without the subscription in your `signUp` function your code can unsubscribe from it and *errors are propagated without any work on your side.* This is also the reason your timeout is hit instead of your mobile number check; you forgot to propagate the error. Instead you tried to return the `Rx.Observable.throw` from within your `subscribeOnError` callback, which has a signature of `onError(error):void`

A good practice is to keep your Rx functions lazy; only execute the code inside when somebody subscribes to it. This helps in reducing hard to trace errors. In your case using the firebase.query() (which returns a promise) you can use `.defer()` to wait with executing the promise until somebody subscribes to your `isUserExisting` function.

```
public isUserExisting(mobile: string): Observable<boolean> {
  if (!mobile) {
      console.log("empty mobile");
      return Observable.throw(new Error("Mobile number cannot be empty"));
  }

  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => firebase.query(() => { }, "/users",
      {
          singleEvent: true,
          orderBy: {
              type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
              value: "mobile"
          },
          range: {
              type: firebase.QueryRangeType.EQUAL_TO,
              value: mobile
          }
      }
  ))
  .do(firebaseResult => console.log('Checking for user success: ' + JSON.stringify(firebaseResult)))
  .filter(firebaseResult => firebaseResult.value != null);
}

public saveUser(user: User) {
  return Observable.defer(() => firebase.push('/users', user))
    .do(result => console.log(`created user with key ${result.key}`))
}
```

Comment: regarding the .defer(), it is best to use it than .fromPromise() since it would wait for subscription before invoking right?

Comment: Also how do I invoke the nested observable saveUser()?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes my experience is that you almost always want to use `defer() `instead of `fromPromise()`. I have updated my original answer to incorporate the `saveUser()` method in it. `signUp(user).subscribe(res => console.log(res))` would be all that you need to get it to run